# WiX Managed Bootstrapper “Failed to resolve source for file” for .cab files

Tags: wix, burn

I have an `.msi` package with 5 external `.cab` files in my bootstrapper application(not being compressed in my bootstrapper application, external) which installs well locally, and has `DownloadUrl` attribute for web-based installation.

But, when I execute my bootstrapper application without its `.msi` file and `.cab` files(not accompanied by them in the same folder, i.e., executed solely in a separate folder), it *cannot* download the `.cab` files although it can download the `.msi` file(log files says that).

So, I added `<Payload>` elements for each `.cab` file under `<MsiPackage>` element with `DownloadUrl` attributes set to their individual URL and `Compressed` attibutes set to `no`. And then, when I execute my boostrapper application solely, it downloads all its files well and installs well.

Should I manage all the `<Payload>` elements for .cab files in `<MsiPakcage>` manually? No automatic download for `.cab` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written only .msi file path in `DownloadUrl` attribute of `MsiPackage` element. But in the source code of Wix Setup BA there was a substitution '{2}' meaning the file name of payload. I followed that and it solved the problem.

For more info see this [link](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/WiX-Managed-Bootstrapper-Failed-to-resolve-source-for-file-for-cab-files-td7598023.html).